# Python script to delete sections of text

Tags: python, beginner, xml

I've been writing a python script to help me clear up some files that contain outdated code, while also serving as a way to learn python. These files have sections of code surrounded with tags on their own lines, I need it to remove both the tags and everything within. While this largely applies to XML documents I am also using this script for several other file types, so XML specific solutions aren't suitable.

I have a working script already but it doesn't look like the most elegant or efficient solution by far, so I would like to see how I can improve it.

Script is called as python `cleanup.py startDeleteTag stopDeleteTag` where the last two arguments are the locations where the code should be deleted and stop being deleted respectfully.

```
import os, sys

def clearFile(path, beginDelete, stopDelete):

  path = os.path.join(path, "fileName.xml")
  input = open(path, "r")
  lines = input.readlines()
  input.close()

  currentFlag = False
  nextFlag = False

  output = open(path, "w")

  for line in lines:
    if nextFlag == True:
      nextFlag = False
      deleteFlag = False

    if beginDelete in line:
      deleteFlag = True
    elif stopDelete in line:
      nextFlag = True

    if deleteFlag == False:
      output.write(line)

thisDirectory = os.getcwd()
for start, dirs, files in os.walk(thisDirectory):
  for f in files:
    if f == "fileName.xml":
      clearFile(thisDirectory, sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

This is the part of the script that checks each line for the start of the section to be deleted (`beginDelete` to `stopDelete`). Because this would leave the end tag in the file I have to use a couple of booleans to specify when the current line needs to be removed but the next line shouldn't be. As an extra, is there a way to improve this to further check for tags that may be on the same line as body of the code? This isn't currently an issue but I'm curious how I would do it if I needed to in future.

As requested, and example file input would look like this:

```
<good>
  keep this
</good>

<bad>
  delete this
</bad>

<good>
  keep this
  <bad>
    delete this
  </bad>
</good>
```

And this would produce the output:

```
<good>
  keep this
</good>


<good>
  keep this

</good>
```

Comment: This code is incomplete. What are `beginDelete` and `stopDelete` (assuming `'<bad>'` and `'</bad>'` from your input file, but who knows). I would also bet that `file` has nothing to do with the [builtin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=file#file), so what is it?

Comment: I've changed `file` to `outout`, it's simply the file that the output is being written too. As stated in the explanation the `beginDelete` and `stopDelete` are the tags that surround the lines that should be deleted (this tag is a variable that is specified when the script starts).

Comment: What I was asking was more _how_ are they defined rather than _what_ they are. Is your snipet of code the body of a function where `path`, `beginDelete`, `stopDelete`, and `output` are parameters? Or is it just a part of your module, verbatim, and these variables are defined earlier? In short, as @SuperBiasedMan said, give us context.

Comment: I've added further context, hopefully this is enough to explain how the current script works. I'm more or less happy with the rest, it's the `clearFile` function that I feel could be greatly improved

Comment: Sorry, overwrote `output` with `file` in my last edit, corrected. I don't know what you mean about the code not executing, that part of the code is copy pasted (just with comments removed) and it works as intended, I just want a more concise way of writing it

Comment: I'm trying out Atom as a text editor and they looked to be on the same line when I copied them, I'm used to notepad++ tab lines. Apologies, corrected

Comment: Trivially, you should factor out the hardcoded `"fileName.xml"` and adhere to [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (four space indents, `snake_case` variables, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

## Program flow

You have a lot of booleans being thrown around and you could clear out a lot. `if nextFlag == True` is the same as `if nextFlag`, and the latter looks neater so stick with it.

For the main flow, you have it in a bit of a mess. You should have only one flag, which denotes lines should be deleted or skipped. Your two flags are entirely confusing the process. Think about it this way, you need a flag to indicate that a part should be skipped. You don't need two values indicating the same thing. So how does that work?

Well obviously you start with looking for `beginDelete`. We need to first check if `deleteFlag` is `True` or `False`. If it's `True` we want it to remain as it is until `stopDelete` is found and skip. So if `deleteFlag` isn't `True`, then we set it to be the result of `beginDelete in line`. You can assign expressions to variables, even if it's a boolean expression. So on this basis we don't need another `if` check, we can just set `deleteFlag` to equal this result directly. Obviously this means the flag is now `True` if we've found `beginDelete` but `False` otherwise.

```
for line in lines:
    if not deleteFlag:
        deleteFlag = beginDelete in line
```

Now, we also need to find `stopDelete` to turn the flag `False` when it's found. This only needs to run if `deleteFlag` is `True`, so it should be an `else` condition:

```
for line in lines:
    if not deleteFlag:
        deleteFlag = beginDelete in line
    else:
        deleteFlag = stopDelete not in line
        continue
```

Now you can see that `deleteFlag` is being set based on whether or not `stopDelete` has been found yet. We're using `not` so that `deleteFlag` remains `True` until `stopDelete` is found. Once that happens, `deleteFlag` is once again `False`. However, since you don't want to write the line where you've just found `stopDelete` then you should use `continue` to skip to the next iteration of the line. `continue` is a keyword that tells a loop to immediately go to the next iteration, ignoring any remaining code in the loop's block.

Now, writing to the file is easy. You just want to write `if not deleteFlag`, ie. if the flag isn't `True`.

```
    if not deleteFlag:
        output.write(line)
```

## Style Notes

Stick to 4 space indentation. It's the Python standard and far more readable for people. Speaking of standards, Python naming uses snake_case, so `beginDelete` should be `begin_delete` etc.

Your names could be better too. You're not really deleting anything. You're 'skipping' or 'ignoring'. You don't really need to include `flag` in the name, using `ignore` would be pretty clear. Also avoid using `input` as that shadows the builtin Python method of the same name. Instead `input_file` or `in_file`. With such a brief usage, you can also use `f`.

Speaking of files, you should use `with` when opening files. It's a context manager that makes file manipulation safer. When using `open` you can easily run into trouble if you don't `close` the file. Sometimes that can happen due to errors, or if you forget to. Which it looks like you actually did with `output`. Using `with` means that a file is always automatically closed, even in the case of errors or exceptions, so it's a more reliable method. This is how you'd use it for `lines`.

```
with open(path, "r") as f:
    f.readlines()
```

The indentation signals how long to leave the file open, and then it's closed once you move out of that block. You should do the same for `output`, also `open` defaults to opening in `"r"` mode so you don't need to specify the argument there.

Also in your final `os.walk` loop you assign `start` and `dirs` but don't seem to use them. If you don't need those values, consider using the names `_` and `__`. That's a Python way of saying that variables are unused throwaways, so people reading your code know they don't matter.

Comment: Just to note, when comparing to singletons, `True`, `False`, `None`, you should use `is`. So `if nextFlag == True` should be `if nextFlag is True`. There is then the exception SuperBiasedMan points out, that Booleans, a sub-set of Singletons, should be compared implicitly. E.g. `if nextFlag`. So when you compare to say `None` you should use `if myVar is None`.

Comment: You can also turn `deleteFlag` into an integer to account for nested flags, just in case. Better be safe than sorry. Something like `deleteFlag += int(beginDelete in line); if deleteFlag: deleteFlag -= int(stopDelete in line); else: output.write(line)`.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger This is good advice, though you'd also want to adjust how you search for closing tags. If you're going to account for nesting you should also account for having the opening and closing tags on the same line.

Comment: Had that in mind too but not enought space inside that comment box to phrase it well.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, without knowing more than the very basics of python meant I couldn't find a way to also delete  the ending tag without using multiple flags, `continue` is exactly what I need. I'm also implementing the other changes you recommended, again these largely seem to be slightly more advanced syntax that I didn't recognise.

Comment: @Psycrow I tried to avoid getting in too deep, if you need to ask more info about anything I've said here please let me know!

Comment: No you've explained everything fantastically, as someone coming from an almost exclusively Java based background there are many syntactic tricks that Python has that I wouldn't have guessed. The only thing I can think of would be if there was a simple way to check for tags inline, however that might be a question for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 5):

### Iterating

Flag variables make stylistically poor code: you test for some condition, set some flag, with the understanding that some other code will later check the flag and vary its behaviour as a result.  Wherever possible, it would be better to just do what you need to do.

This is a particularly tricky loop to reformulate.  Since you are trying to skip over some items as you iterate, I'd drop the [`for … in …` loop](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) so that we can access the underlying [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) directly.

### Decomposing the problem

Splitting off some of the work into a `clearFile()` function is a good idea.  However, `clearFile()` is still quite complex: not only does it need to figure out what lines to include or exclude, it is also responsible for assembling the filename, opening the file for reading, and replacing the file's contents.

Just figuring out which lines to include or exclude is a complex enough problem that it deserves to be its own function.  I'd make it a generator: the function `yield`s lines to be included as it encounters them.  The caller can decide what to do with those lines.

Another sign that the responsibilities are suboptimally divided is that `"fileName.xml"` is hard-coded in two places.

### Input / output

Instead of calling `open()` twice on the file, just `open()` it once in `'r+'` mode.

You can just use `'.'` to refer to the current directory.

### Style

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) specifies four spaces for indentation.  Considering that whitespace is significant in Python, this is an important convention to follow.

PEP 8 also states that `under_scores` are preferred.

`clearFile()` suggests a more drastic operation than just redacting lines between markers.

In my personal opinion, the names `beginDelete` and `stopDelete` feel mismatched.  more natural word pairs are *begin–end* and *start–stop*.

### Suggested solution

```
import os
import sys

def filter_lines(f, start_delete, stop_delete):
    """
    Given a file handle, generate all lines except those between the specified
    text markers.
    """
    lines = iter(f)
    try:
        while True:
            line = next(lines)
            if start_delete in line:
                # Discard all lines up to and including the stop marker
                while stop_delete not in line:
                    line = next(lines)
                line = next(lines)
            yield line
    except StopIteration:
        return

def redact_files(start_delete, stop_delete):
    """
    Edit all files named "fileName.xml" under the current directory, stripping
    out text between the specified text markers.
    """
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
        if 'fileName.xml' in filenames:
            with open(os.path.join(dirpath, 'fileName.xml'), 'r+') as f:
                filtered = list(filter_lines(f, start_delete, stop_delete))
                f.seek(0)
                f.writelines(filtered)
                f.truncate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    redact_files(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

As @SuperBiasedMan pointed out, you only need one flag. The logic for this flag can be simplified to just this:

```
for line in lines:
    if beginDelete in line:
        deleteFlag = True
    if stopDelete in line:
        deleteFlag = False
```

(You can set and unset the flag without checking what its current state is.)